# CentOS VM is slow on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, performance, virtual-machine, vmware, centos

Setup/version numbers

**Guest**

```
OS: CentOS 6.0 64-bit (installed from LiveCD)
RAM: 1 GB
Processors: 1
Hard Disk: 20 GB
```

**Host**

```
System: Lenovo T410
OS: Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit  (Build 7600) 6.1.7600
RAM: 4GB
Processor: i5-M520
Hard Disk: 80GB SSD
```

**Environment / Configuration**

```
Tool: VMware Player 4.0.1 build-528992 
SELinux: Disabled
BIOS: VT Enabled
```

So here's the problem: it's *slowwwwww!*

I'm using this primarily for LAMP-stack web development, and running PHP from it is just really slow (operations that should take less than a second are taking up to 10 seconds)

Do you think this is hardware-related only, or is the a configuration or other issue going on?

Comment: Give it all the cores, and disable memory page trimming in Player. It won't use resources, unless it needs to. (I always run VMs with all the cores given to them.)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be a little faster.  Not great yet, but better. If you post this as an answer I'll at least upvote it :D

Comment: Uhm... another idea: Give VMWare Workstation Preview a try. It's free to use until October or so. Maybe that will help too. (Remember, always install VMWare-tools inside the guest!)